# interval proof using points

Tags: calculus

So this is for my advanced calculus class (Real Analysis II) which is a proof class.
 The question is:

If $a<b$ are points in an interval $D$, show that $[a,b]$ $\subset$ $D$.

I feel like its obvious, but I'm not sure how to prove. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: What is the definition of an *interval*?

Comment: I haven't written a formal proof, but I feel like if a <b are points in D, wouldn't [a,b] be a subset of D by default? @Mahidevran

Comment: @ZoëSoriano I've gotta ask, did you not do proofs in Real Analysis I?

Comment: @mapierce271 I did do proofs but I just feel like this question is very obvious and it is basically the definition of an interval, so I'm not quite sure how to prove it.

Comment: What *is* the definition of an "interval"? Since "interval" is the only real term in that claim, I would assume that your text/professor gave a definition of "interval." Else, there isn't much to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an element $t\in[a,b]$, since $D$ is an interval, let say $D=(c,d)$, and $a,b\in D$ with $a<b$, we have the chain of inequalities $$c<a\le t\le b<d.$$ From this it follows that $t\in D$, thus $[a,b]\subset D$.